Vercel Feature Flag
I had implemented Vercel Feature flags with Vercel Toolbar. But the issue is When I enable or disable any feature, It only persisit in user's session and for only that user who is applying this feature flag.
What I want is, administration (users with specified emails) should be able to set those flags in toolbar and this configuration/UI change should be visible to all the non-administration users.
Is there any way I can do this? or any alternative?
